# What is Fermi age? What does it represent?

Tags: nuclear-physics, nuclear-engineering

What does the lethargy represent? What are its units? What is the range of the lethargy? (Is it between 0 and 1?)

The definition of lethargy is:

$u = \ln \frac{E_0}{E}$

and the average increase in lethargy is $\xi = \bar{\Delta u}$

$\bar{\xi} (E) = \frac{\text{Sum}( \xi_i \Sigma_{s,i} (E) ) }{\Sigma_s (E)}$

where $\Sigma_s$ is the scattering cross section.

(This is the lethargy for a mixture of isotopes.)

What does the Fermi age represent?

$\tau (E) = \int_E^{E_0} \frac{D(E')}{\xi \Sigma_s (E')} \frac{dE'}{E'}$

where $D$ is the diffusion constant.

with Fermi equation being:

$\nabla^2 q (\vec{r}, \tau) = \frac{\partial q}{\partial \tau}$

where $q$ represents the slowing-down source (neutrons slowing down from fast to thermal).

I understand the mathematics, but I am not sure if I understand the meaning of these physical concepts.

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of a previous question, https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/607955/what-is-the-fermi-age-what-does-it-represent

Comment: I deleted the other question because it was unclear.

Comment: I think you mean "...lethargy for a population of neutrons."

Comment: The sum means the sum over mixtures. All of this is about populations of neutrons.

Comment: *I deleted the other question because it was unclear.* You were supposed to *edit* the other question to make it clear. This one still is not clear. What is $D$? What is $q$? Why is there a functional derivative on the right side of your final equation?

Comment: Yes, but you wrote *nucleotides*.

Comment: Welcome @Maj! In the future please don’t delete and re-post a closed question; instead you can [edit] it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The energy of neutrons in nuclear reactors cover many orders of magnitude, which can range from from $10^7$ eV down to about $10^{-5}$ eV.  When neutrons scatter, the amount of energy lost is a function of the log of the energy.  Therefore, it is often convenient to transform the energy into the log of energy, which we call "lethergy".  When a neutron downscatters, it tends to lose energy in equal lethergy segments.  The transformation is a simple mathematical transformation.  Lethergy is a unitless quantity, as shown in your first equation.  $E_0$ is an arbitrary value, often taken as 10 MeV.

The word "lethergy" literally translates to "laziness", so as a neutron loses energy, it gains lethergy (laziness).

Fermi age is an old concept that is really only valid for neutron scattering in graphite. It was important in early reactors, but has lost favor as all commercial reactors use water or heavy water moderator since at least 1960.  You usually only find discussions Fermi age in older textbooks.  Basically, the Fermi age is a measure of how far a neutron travels in graphite, similar to the "diffusion length".  It is called "age" because the neutron lifetime is proportional to how long it takes to slow down in a moderator.

I noticed that you are asking many questions that can be found in beginning nuclear engineering textbooks. Are you reading the textbooks before asking questions, or just skimming through the topics?

Comment: I am following a course in nuclear physics, but I have a hard time with some of the concepts involved, as I am not as familiar with them (most other students seem to have already some background in the subject).